# Export Pd patch to the Apple App Store

Tags: ios, export, app-store, puredata

I'm new to Pd and would like to know whether it's possible to directly/indirectly export a Pd patch to the Apple App Store. For example, MobMuPlat is on the App Store and I think this was created using Pd?

Has anyone tried exporting an OpenFrameworks app to the App store using ofxPd library?

Answer (score 3):

MobMuPlat (and PdParty, and many many other audio apps) use [libpd](http://libpd.cc/) to embed PureData as the audio engine. There's even a [whole book](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/making-musical-apps/9781449331375/) by the author of libpd (though some of the development steps are out of date). MobMuPlat and PdParty are also both open source on github.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

You can create and upload apps made with ofxPd to the Apple App Store.

ofxPd allows you to open Pd patches in your openFrameworks app.
The main usage is to use Pd as an audio engine for your app so you need to create the GUI part using openFrameworks or other libraries and make it communicate with your Pd patch.

---

**Added:**

You can also use Ofelia to upload your Pd patch to the App Store. You can even create Web applications using it.

Please check https://github.com/cuinjune/ofxOfelia